# EF6 Entity through different phases

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

### Background

I am putting together an internal company system to manage our sales program (basically a custom CRM). As a part of this we have identified a 'life-cycle' that each client will go through as they progress through the various stages of a sale. The challenge is that each phase adds additional data to the previous phase.

We are using EF6 (code-first) with ASP.NET MVC 5.

### The Question

What is the best Entity Framework model for allowing each phase to extend the previous one? I thought maybe something like:

```
//don't worry about relationships to other classes, it's just an example

public class Lead //phase 1
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class Prospect : Lead //phase 2
{
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts {get; set;}
    public virtual Quote Quote {get; set;}
}

public class Buyer : Prospect //phase 3
{
    public string Hypervisor {get; set;}
    public IPAddress AllocatedIP {get; set;}
}
```

The thinking here is that each phase extends the previous one to add additional properties. However my understanding is that in order to facilitate the change we would have to detach the Client, convert/map them into the new (more derived) type, fill in the missing properties then re-attach them. Seems a bit dirty.

Any and all EF-genius comments appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application? My first thought is to make all of these classes use the same table structure with a discriminator column. But I'm not familiar with your requirements so you'll need to evaluate each inheritance pattern yourself.

Comment: Yes I have read through it, and have EF inheritance elsewhere - EF will implement the Discriminator automatically. The question is more about whether there are any better alternatives than what I've suggested.

Comment: Is there a problem with mapping it onto a single table? The different phases sound like a business requirement, not really a data structure.

Comment: You're absolutely right - but my instinct (as a DB Developer) is to try and avoid a table full of nulls that don't apply, hence trying to find an object model that captures the accurate state of things.

Comment: You could go with a "flatter" design than a hierarchical one. A table "Person" with nullable FKs to Lead, Prospect, and Buyer. The state of a "Person" is simply an integer check for an id value. Advancing someone to the next state is just adding an id value to their record.